# Can Protractor select an element using two "by." statements?

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

My team's web app has several elements with identical bindings and several elements with identical CSS. In my Protractor test, I would need to use both by.css and by.binding in order to capture the element I'm looking for.

Here's an example section of our Angular markup:

```
<!-- eiHand -->
<td ng-show="assessment.type === 'EI'">{{assessment.ratedDate || assessment.scores.eiHand[0].ratedDate | date:'MMMM d, y h:mm a'}}</td>
<td ng-show="assessment.type === 'EI'">{{assessment.raterName || assessment.scores.eiHand[0].rater}}</td>
<td ng-show="assessment.type === 'EI'">{{assessment.averageScore * 100 | number:0}}</td>
<!-- lsa -->
<td ng-show="assessment.type === 'LSA'">{{assessment.ratedDate || assessment.scores.lsa[0].ratedDate | date:'MMMM d, y h:mm a'}}</td>
<td ng-show="assessment.type === 'LSA'">{{assessment.raterName || assessment.scores.lsa[0].rater}}</td>
<td ng-show="assessment.type === 'LSA'">{{assessment.averageScore | number:1}}</td>
```

The HTML generated by the browser looks like this:

```
<!-- eiHand -->
<td ng-show="assessment.type === 'EI'" class="ng-binding ng-hide"></td>
<td ng-show="assessment.type === 'EI'" class="ng-binding ng-hide"></td>
<td ng-show="assessment.type === 'EI'" class="ng-binding ng-hide">500</td>
<!-- lsa -->
<td ng-show="assessment.type === 'LSA'" class="ng-binding">December 1, 2013 5:00 AM</td>
<td ng-show="assessment.type === 'LSA'" class="ng-binding">John Doe</td>
<td ng-show="assessment.type === 'LSA'" class="ng-binding">5.0</td>
```

I want to select the element with the binding `assessment.raterName` and the CSS `ng-show="assessment.type === 'LSA'"`, unless the LSA's are invisible and the EI's are visible, in which case I'd use the other assessment.type. I know how to do either of these individually, but I'm not sure how to zero in on an element with both.

I've tried using `element(by.css([the_table])).all(by.binding([see above])).element(by.css([see above]))` but I get the error `Object [object Object] has no method 'element'`.

I also tried `element(by.css([the_table])).all(by.binding([see above])).get([a numerical expression based on the value of the assessment.type variable])` but it gives the error `Object 2000 has no method 'apply'`.

I'm sure there's an elegant solution for this, but I don't know what it is.

**The ugly solution**

What I'm using now is `element(by.css([the_table])).element(by.binding('assessment.scores.' + (assessmentType == "LSA" ? "lsa" : "eiHand") + '[0].rater'))`. It works in this specific case but doesn't answer the broader question, so I'm not posting it as an answer.

Comment: Could show the HTML generated when you open up the page in the browser? Also, is this always 3 cells per each assessment type? Thanks.

Comment: Hello again, @alecxe. I've added that HTML to the question. Yes, there are always three cells per assessment type, but the zen-programmer in me doesn't want to use an index, because the app is still in testing and minor rearrangements of the UI are fairly likely.